# Django REST: weird dot in url-reverse

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The `router` code:

```
...
domain_nested_routers_lookup = 'domain'
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('accounts', DomainViewSet)
...
domains_router = NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'accounts', lookup=domain_nested_routers_lookup)
```

The reason for such a move is because project old API used the term `domain`, that is not getting changed to `account`.

The `serializer`code:

```
class DomainSerializer(...):
    link = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='domain-detail', lookup_field='short_name')
```

Now the problem is that this code:

```
self.api_reverse('domain-detail', self.domain.id)
```

returns:

```
u'/rest/accounts/domain_0.1'
```

And I don't understand by what magic `.1` is added (1 is an `id` of `domain` object).

The correct output should be:

`u'/rest/accounts/domain_0`

Comment: api_reverse isn't a Django REST framework function so there's no way we can help without its code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for an answer and help from **2ps**, I have figured out the way:

```
self.api_reverse('domain-detail'
```

In my case, I had to look better how `api_reverse` is defined.

Answer (score 2):

So you can pass in a set of parameters to reverse if there are parameters defined in your URL route.  I haven’t worked with django REST before specifically, but I would try naming your parameter:

```
self.api_reverse('domain-detail', args=[ self.domain.id ])
```

OR -

```
self.api_reverse('domain-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.domain.id })
```

Which will probably generate a route like:

```
/rest/accounts/domain_0/1
```

Comment: THis gives: `*** ValueError: Don't mix *args and **kwargs in call to reverse()!`

Comment: Where did you call `self.api_reverse` from?  i.e., what class did you call it in?

Comment: The reason I ask is because the REST framework documents `reverse` as — http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/reverse/.  I assumed that api_reverse was the same thing because it is not documented anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, but what does `self` refer to.  The unit test class?

Comment: Can you please post the definition of `def api_reverse(self, . . .)`?

Comment: The `self` is `<domain.tests.test_restapi.AccountRESTApiTest testMethod=test_detail_head>`